# Possible to call external tool several times with ToolTask?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is it possible to launch an external tool several times with different options using just one MSBuild ToolTask call?

A little background: We develop a VisualStudio Plugin using Tasks and ToolTasks for auto-code-generation. We want to write a ToolTask wrapper around nvcc to generate .ptx-files from .cu-(CUDA)-code. Each time the ToolTask is called, it gets a list of .cu-files and needs to call nvcc. nvcc has the option to take several source files as inputs, but has no option to specify individual output files. This is only possible if only one input file is given, then the -o-option works fine. As the files contained in the list are located in different folders and the generated code shall be placed besides them, we need to specify the outputs explicitely and thus call the tool several times somehow.

Our previous version of the tool handled only one file per ToolTask-call, but we want to re-design the tool to work with the full list at once. Is this possible?

Cheers